# Javascript get last part of variable strings

Tags: javascript

I have strings like that;

```
a-variable-part[]
another-string[x]
```

without knowing the length of each string i want to separate the first part of the string from what there's inside []

in the examples above I want to get:

- "a-variable-part", ""
- "another-string", "x"

do you know how?

Comment: Do you know how log the part is you're after? because _"not knowing the string length"_ doesn't really make sense. (`someString.length`). Also: what does that last part look like? is it _"delimited"_ by some characters, like `ignore this, but [this is what I need]`? Some more info, and, as ever: _what have you tried_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run this:

```
'another-string[x]'.slice(0, -1).split('[');
```

it will give you an array of two elements: `["another-string", "x"]`

Answer (score 4):

You can use a regex to find the two pieces like this:

```
function getParts(str) {
    var matches = str.match(/(^.*?)\[(.*?)\]/);
    if (matches) {
        return({first: matches[1], second: matches[2]});
    }
    return(null);
}
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/Nn63v/

To explain the regex, it matches a first group of characters that goes from the start of the string up until the first [ char.  Then, it matches a second group of characters that is between the [ and ].

Answer (score 0):

At a basic level this will work:

```
var myString = 'foo[bar]';

var bitInBrackets = myString.split('[')[1].split(']')[0];// will be string 'bar'
```

If you're going to be doing a lot of string manipulation it's probably worth learning a bit about regex, but if this is all you want to do, and you know the strings will follow this format, the above will work fine.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do this with a regex

```
var result = input.match( /^([^\[]+)\[([^\]]+)\]$/ );
```